# php template engine for existing webpage

Tags: php, template-engine, tinybutstrong

I am working with a pretty simple php template right now, stored in one index.php and fetch the files via a GET and access the files like: http://mydomain.com/index.php?page=news if the file is called news.php. See the code snippet below.

```
 <?
        $fileend = ".php";
        $file="{$_GET["page"]}$fileend";
        $news="news.php";
        if(file_exists($file))
            include($file);
        else
            include($news);
    ?>
```

Now I want to use a templage engine where I can have different  tags for each page, still I don't want to change my file system. Right now my php files looks like this:

```
<h1>Page Title</h1>
<p>Page Content</p>
```

I don't use a header as the files are included in my index.php.

I have looked at TinyButStrong and other engines. But I don't know how I should proceed. It should be quite easy. Please let me know how I can do when I don't want to change a lot in my file structure and keep it simple.

Comment: Please be aware that your current application is vulnerable to file inclusion. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_file_inclusion

Answer (score 1):

Try the [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) template engine. It is easy to use and you can use a dedicated template folder. I don't know whether you will have to change a lot because I don't know your file structure ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know smarty but I don't know if it's the best solution. My file structure is pretty simple. I have the files in the main folder and in subdirectories. I want to access my files simply through typing the url index.php?page=2011/page1 if the file is in the subdirectory 2011. I don't want to create a .tpl file for every page but I still want to have different title tags in the header.

Comment: You can use html files also in smarty and use $smarty->display($_GET['yourTemplateFile']);
But there may exist better engines of course.

Answer (score 0):

You might give `Zend_Layout` and `Zend_View` a try. You don't need to use the MVC part of Zend Framework for this. Biggest plus when using these 2 classes is that templates are simply PHP files. You don't have to use `Zend_Layout` though, but when working with layouts it does make things easier.

Comment: So, need I a template for every singe file or is it enough with one main template (index.php) where all my other files are included?

Comment: You can have your index.php be the entry point which decides which template (individual files) to include. Don't stuff everything together in 1 file, it makes maintenance a living hell.

Answer (score 0):

Another template engine what you can use is Separate (see http://separate.esud.info/). It is possible to include files with

```
<!-- INCLUDE filename -->
```